# Easiest way of checking the truthy of a value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

While programming with javascript, I come in some situations that I have a condition an wonder what values will pass that condition (if it will be truthy).

The solution I came up with is open the console in chrome and type `if(foo) {true}` and if the `foo` is truthy, it returns `true`, otherwise `false`.

An example of that is when I have some expression (`foo`) that won't return only `true`/`false` values. Inside the `if` it can return alot of things depending on the input (sometimes string, or number or maybe `NaN`).

But I fell that writing a `if` for that is too much.

Is there a easiest way of checking the truthy of a value in javascript?

## Edit:

I'm looking for the easiest way of checking the truthy of a value, not just how to check and as I said in my question, I already do `if(foo) {true}` to check, but I'm looking for a easiest way

Comment: `!!something` performs the same transformation that an `if` statement performs.

Comment: `const thruthness = !!yourVariable`, or better yet `const thruthness = Boolean(yourVariableOrExpression)`

Comment: well, that did the trick, thanks guys. If you post the answer, I will accept it

Comment: `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `0`, `NaN` and `""` *(emty string)* are falsy, **everything** else is truthy; like a single space `" "` or any of these values as string, etc.

Comment: Also relevant: https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/

Answer (score -2):

I would use a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) operator to shorthand the if-statement.

The result is something like this:

```js
const foo = true;
console.log(foo ? 'truthy' : 'falsy'); // returns truthy
```

Comment: If you're using ternary you don't need to convert it to boolean, that happens automatically.

Comment: @ritaj, correct. Edited my answer.